# Restkit: Handling dynamic nesting attributes only returns one object

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I receive JSON code that looks like this:

```
{
  "rent": {
    "items": [

    ],
    "total": 0
  },
  "upcoming": {
    "items": [

    ],
    "total": 0
  },
  "watchnow": {
    "items": [

    ],
    "total": 0
  }
}
```

I want the keys, i.e. "rent", "upcoming" and "watchnow" as a property on the mapped object, so I add a NSString property called **searchSection** to the class I'm using and then create this mapping:

```
RKObjectMapping *searchResultsMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[TDXSearchResults class]];
[searchResultsMapping addAttributeMappingFromKeyOfRepresentationToAttribute:@"searchSection"];
```

Shouldn't my `mappingResult.array` then contain three TDXSearchResults objects, each with either "rent", "upcoming" or "watchnow" in its `searchSection` property? I only get one TDXSearchResults in the array and this confuses me greatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only expect 1 result because your source data is only 1 object (and you must only have 1 response descriptor).

If you want 3 result objects then you should use either:

1. `forceCollectionMapping` on the mapping
2. 3 response descriptors, each with the same mapping for `items` and each using a different keypath (rent / upcoming / watchnow).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you led me to re-read the documentation which led me to setting `searchResultsMapping.forceCollectionMapping` which is what was missing.

Comment: Excellent point, that is the best solution, and I forgot about it to! Updated the answer for future readers.